# How to restrict iframe content height and width?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I am trying to restrict the width height inside iframe.

for example:

```
 <iframe src = 'http://www.yahoo.com' style="width: 130px; height: 100px;> </iframe>
```

I want `www.yahoo.com` as small as my `iframe`. In other words, squeeze the yahoo page.

Are there anyways to work around this or this is an dead end. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to scale the frame to a smaller size (likely reducing its usability), but you can't modify the style of the iframe content from outside of it

[Javascript / CSS: set (firefox) zoom level of iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660659/javascript-css-set-firefox-zoom-level-of-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write your code like this
    src="www.yahoo.com" width="200" height="200"